# mPDF TOC is not using charset_in of the document

Tags: php, mpdf, tableofcontents, charset

The TOC generated by $mpdf->TOCpagebreakByArray() is displaying "1.2 AvaliaÃ§Ã£o de Riscos" instead of "1.2 Avaliação de Riscos" that is correct inside the document.

TOC is not using the definition of the document:
$mpdf->charset_in = 'ISO-8859-1';

How can I correct this on the TOC ?

Comment: Does anyone had this same problem?  In mPDF the TableOfContent functionallity does not uses the correct charset.

Comment: Em português: Utilizando o mPDF (classe PHP para geração de PDF), existe uma funcionalidade para criar um sumário de modo automático com base nas tag H1, H2, H3 contidas no documento, porém essa funcionalidade não está respeitando o charset do documento que está com a acentuação totalmente correta, mas no sumário (TOC) que é gerado automático, as palavras acentuadas saem com acentuação incorreta, conforme postado no caput desta postagem.  Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir este problema?